# SSL certificate issue with OpenID Connect and ASP.Net Core 2.1

Tags: asp.net-core, ssl-certificate, openid, openid-connect, asp.net-core-2.1

**Disclaimer - I am new to OpenID Connect and ASP.Net Core -**

I am using OpenId Connect in an ASP.Net Core 2.1 MVC application for user authentication. When I run the application it redirects me to the Identity Provider where I need to put my credentials (Username and Password) and if the authentication is successful then it will proceed with the other steps (providing auth code, access-token etc). However, post login it throws the below error --
[image]

This is quite clear that it is related to the SSL certificate but I am not able to resolve it in .Net Core 2.1. Please be informed that I implemented the same solution in an ASP.Net MVC 5 application with the same OpenID Connect configuraion and there also I faced the same issue but I resolved that by using the below code in the Configuration Method of StartUp.cs file (only in Dev and not in Production) --

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
```

Please suggest how can I achieve the same in ASP.Net Core 2.1. While looking for solutions, I found that a lot of people are suggesting to create a Custom HTTP Client Handler with some configuration to ignore SSL certificate and then using that HTTP client to make all HTTP calls further but please be informed that the calls here are made internally to the server by the OpenId Connect itself. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Amit Anand

Comment: When you say post login, do you mean after you authenticated at Identity Provider, the redirect to your callback url throws this exception or when you got the access token and trying to using this access token to call an api than the exception occurs?

Comment: Take a look here for an easy solution: https://mcguirev10.com/2018/01/04/localhost-ssl-identityserver-certificates.html

Comment: @ Elendil Zheng-MSFT
I am getting this exception when it is redirected to the callback url after successful authentication at the Identity Provider.